# Gconf Dconf and Gsettings

Tags: linux

What is the difference between all of these programs? I read that some act as a back-end but I cannot find details.  How are they all related and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gconf is the older Gnome configuration system, and dconf is newer. There is currently a transition from Gconf to dconf happening.  See  https://askubuntu.com/a/91409 for a good answer. I guess it's progress...

Comment: Thank you, How is gsettings related to both of them?

Comment: Gsettings is the higher level API that hides the actual backend implementation. It's what most devs should use.

Comment: so gsettings will know which you have installed and acts as an abstraction for dconf or gconf?